# Knot theory: Braids

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Show by using a picture, that the two braids $\sigma_{i} \sigma_{i+1} \sigma_{i}$ and $\sigma_{i+1} \sigma_{i} \sigma_{i+1}$ are equivalent.

This is 5.26 in knot book by Colin Adams. Need some assistance

Comment: Did you try drawing both braids?

Comment: You need assistance drawing? Have you not seen braid diagrams before? You can look them up on Wikipedia and elsewhere. (Are they never mentioned or shown in your book by 5.26?) They go either top-down or left-right, and we multiply braids by concatenating their diagrams in the same direction.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the drawing of pictures, changing your $\sigma$ to the $T$ below:

[image]

You can find this graph anywhere by searching for the braid group or Yang-Baxter equation.